# What is the difference between a half metal (HM) and a spin gapless semiconductor (SGS)?

Tags: band-structure, density-of-states, spintronics

I would like to know what is the difference between a **Half metal (HM)** and a **Spin Gapless Semiconductor (SGS)** in terms of *definition* and *DOS/Bandstructure appearance*.

Comment: Is there any additional context you can provide on your question? Also, you have a different acronym in your title (HSC) than in your question (SGC). Is this a third term you wanted to ask about or an alternative abbreviation of the same concept?

Comment: Concerning the acronym it was just typing a mistake, and about additional context I am familiar with Half-metals but I still don't the know what is Spin Gapless Semi-conductor

Comment: Maybe this article will help, I don't have the time to read through it properly though right now to make a proper answer. https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/5.0028918

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept of spin gapless semiconductors (SGS) was proposed in this paper: [PRL 100, 156404 (2008)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.100.156404).

- In quantum solid-state band theory, materials in nature are generally classified as insulators, semiconductors, metals, semimetals, and half-metals based on the electronic band structures (density of states or band structure), as shown below.

[image]

- (a): Metal
- (b): Semiconductor or Insulator by the gap value
- (c): Semimetal (The valence band and conduction band are touching slightly.)
- (d): Half-metal
- Energy band diagrams for spin gapless semiconductors with linear dispersion between energy and momentum.

[image]

- Energy band diagrams for spin gapless semiconductors with parabolic dispersion between energy and momentum.

[image]

Compared to the band structure of half metal, one spin channel of SGS is touching slightly (gapless).

Take a careful look at the cited paper and then you will figure out the difference!